# Dynamic Data Masking: Looking for options or techniques to limit unmasking data to a stored procedure call

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Currently, I can mask/unmask data with the approach explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=azuresqldb-current

I am looking for options to limit unmasking data to stored procedure calls only.

That means non-dbo users always get masked data. Only the ones has right to call a stored proc can get unmasked version of the data.

I am using SQL Azure, but I am hoping to find a technique that work consistent accross the SQL Server product line.

Comment: You might be looking for the `WITH EXECUTE AS` clause in your stored procedure definitions - this enables a stored procedure to be run in the security context of a user you specify: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @EdHarper, yes that is how I ended up make it working yeterday. I could not find any other solution, other than CREATE PROC ... WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER